# dynamically disable/enable inputs in activiti explorer

Tags: workflow, activiti, bpmn

is there any way to dynamically enable/disable inputs (form properties) in activiti explorer?
I'm trying to do it like:

```
<activiti:formProperty id="field" name="field" writable="${is_field_writable}"></activiti:formProperty>
```

but it's not working

Answer (score 0):

The form-functionality in the Activiti Explorer is very limited since it is just a demo application to demonstrate the Activiti APIs. It is not possible to dynamically enable or disable form-fields by default.

You could extend the Activiti Explorer to implement this feature on your own or you could integrate another form-technology which is more mature. For example, we use XForms in combination with Activiti.